# How to set - Method Response HTTP - Status: Proxy in APIGW via CFT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, devops

For last couple of day's I am working on cloud formation template which will create a API Gateway hooked up with a lambda behind it, The APIGW will just have a {proxy+} resource with an ANY method and I want to handle all the logic in the backend lambda.

I was able to create the same via console :

[image]

Now I want to replicate the same via cloud formation template
My current CloudFormation template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: My API Gateway and Lambda function

Parameters:
  apiGatewayName:
    Type: String
    Default: proxy-apigw
  apiGatewayStageName:
    Type: String
    Default: v1
  apiGatewayHTTPMethod:
    Type: String
    Default: ANY
  lambdaFunctionName:
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: "[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
    Default: proxy-lambda

Resources:
  apiGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Description: Example API Gateway
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - REGIONAL
      Name: !Ref apiGatewayName

  apiGatewayLambdaResource:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      PathPart: '{proxy+}'
      ParentId: !GetAtt apiGateway.RootResourceId

  apiGatewayLambdaResourceMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      ResourceId: !Ref apiGatewayLambdaResource
      HttpMethod: ANY
      Integration:
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Uri: !Sub 
          - >-
            arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
      MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200
          ResponseModels: { "application/json": "Empty" }

  apiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    DependsOn:
      - apiGatewayLambdaResourceMethod
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      StageName: !Ref apiGatewayStageName

  lambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          exports.handler = async (event) => {
              // TODO implement
              const response = {
                  statusCode: 200,
                  body: JSON.stringify(event),
              };
              return response;
          };
      Description: Example Lambda function
      FunctionName: !Ref lambdaFunctionName
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt lambdaIAMRole.Arn
      Runtime: nodejs12.x

  lambdaApiGatewayInvoke:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      # note: if route *not* at API Gateway root, `SourceArn` would take the form of:
      #               arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${apiGateway}/${apiGatewayStageName}/${apiGatewayHTTPMethod}/PATH_PART
      SourceArn: !Sub arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${apiGateway}/${apiGatewayStageName}/${apiGatewayHTTPMethod}/

  lambdaIAMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
      Policies:
        - PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Effect: Allow
                Resource:
                  - !Sub arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/${lambdaFunctionName}:*
          PolicyName: lambda

  lambdaLogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub /aws/lambda/${lambdaFunctionName}
      RetentionInDays: 90

Outputs:
  apiGatewayInvokeURL:
    Value: !Sub https://${apiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${apiGatewayStageName}

  lambdaArn:
    Value: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
```

With this I was able to create a {proxy+} resource under the root and a ANY method associated with the /{proxy+} resource, but when I call APIGW URL I am getting internal server error

```
patelnab@3c22fb980312 ~ % curl --request GET https://nx9gwoz5de.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/test/route
{"message": "Internal server error"}%
```

This is APIGW looks, which is got created by Cloudformation template

[image]

One difference, I was able to point out is in `Method Response`, The one I created via console has `HTTP Status: Proxy` where as the which was created via CloudFormation doesn't have that. I tried searching in the documentation but could not find much on this. Any help on this is highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your permissions are incorrect. You are missing `/*`:

```
  lambdaApiGatewayInvoke:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      # note: if route *not* at API Gateway root, `SourceArn` would take the form of:
      #               arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${apiGateway}/${apiGatewayStageName}/${apiGatewayHTTPMethod}/PATH_PART
      SourceArn: !Sub arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${apiGateway}/${apiGatewayStageName}/${apiGatewayHTTPMethod}/*
```

And if you want to polulate `MethodRequest`, you can do:

```
      Integration:
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Uri: !Sub
          - >-
            arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
        IntegrationResponses:
          - ResponseTemplates:
              application/json: ""
            StatusCode: 200
        PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES
```

Comment: this works perfectly, this is what was missing. Can you share what does this `PassthroughBehavior` signifies